# How can I test/send multiple (fake) ajax-requests at once to a (node.js) server?

Tags: ajax, node.js, testing, request

At a certain point your (node.js) app works good with your single requests, and you would like to see what happens if fifty people use it at the same time. What will happen to the memory usage? What happens to the overall speed of the response?

I reckon this kind of testing is done a lot, so I was thinking there might be a relatively easy helper program for that.

By relatively easy I mean something convenient like [POSTman - REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) is for single request and response testing.

What is your recommended (or favorite) method of testing this?

Comment: Apache Bench is another option: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/689.cfm

Answer (score 2):

We use http://jmeter.apache.org/ , free and powerful ... you can set test use cases and run them